# Apache mod_rewrite with multiple parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've been struggling to get the following rewrite working

```
^/agatedepot/([0-9.]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z._]+)\?doc-id=([0-9a-zA-Z._\-]+)
```

to

```
/agateDepot.php?date=$1&filename=$2&doc-id=$3
```

I know that mod_rewrite is working.  I know that it is reading the .htaccess file, I'm just not seeing any redirecting happening.  Here's what I have in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/agatedepot/([0-9.]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z._]+)\?doc-id=([0-9a-zA-Z._\-]+) /agateDepot.php?date=$1&filename=$2&doc-id=$3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I imagine it is something simple, but I have not been able to figure it out.  No errors in the Apache error log, and the access log is simply recording a 404.

Comment: This question is better suited to ServerFault.

Comment: You should give an example for concrete URL for tests.

Comment: sure

/agatedepot/2010.01.03/a_bunch_of_text.txt?doc-id=xt.l.nfl.com.7182032

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL query is not part of the URL path and thus can not be processed with [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). Here you need an additional [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). Additionally, when you use mod_rewrite in an .htaccess file, the per-directory path prefix is removed before testing the rules and appended back after applying a rule. So in your case you would need to remove the leading `/` from your pattern.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^doc-id=([0-9a-zA-Z._\-]+)$
RewriteRule ^agatedepot/([0-9.]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z._]+)$ agateDepot.php?date=$1&filename=$2&doc-id=%1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!

Comment: If you just want to append the original requested query to the new one, you could also set the *QSA* flag.

Answer (score 0):

Question mark `?` marks the start of the QueryString, hence it's not analyzed by the `RewriteRule`. You should replace the `?` or analyze it with `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ...`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add  [`RewriteBase /`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) and skip the first slash (i.e. `^agatedepot...`)