# What other get method characters can be used? aside from question mark?

Tags: php, get

the normal get:
http://localhost/get.php?id=2&get=row

can it be done like this?

http://localhost/get.php&id=2&get=row

or in other way.

When a user make a parameter to my site like

http://test.com/**?url=http://localhost/sample/**

or what if it contains a "?id=234"

so the new url is http://test.com/?url=http://localhost/smaple?id=1234

it creates now a 2 question mark.

Comment: No, the latter won't work.
What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: this is the url http://localhost/sample/?id=234 and when i am done saving the data from the above url he should be redirected to http://localhost/sample/?id=234?uid=ao6klc2sgvc9lkj23sk53osij04da409dfbb54e&gps=true

Comment: Please post the expected result, the link you posted is not a valid URL.

Comment: Could you provide us with a bit more context? Like why you're asking it and what you tend to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user make a parameter to your site, he **has** to [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) such data, so, it's going to be

```
http://test.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsmaple%3Fid%3D1234
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is not possible, at least not using `&` and `?` as separator characters. They have a defined meaning in a URL and cannot be used beyond that meaning. Repeating the characters will result in an invalid URL. It will probably work in most browsers but it's bad practice.

Consider sticking with the classical `?param=value&param2=value2` notation. Why do you want to change that in the first place? Is there a specific reason?

If you really want to do this, and are fine with some other character to separate the parameters from each other, you can use one of these two methods.

**PATH_INFO**

If the `AcceptPathInfo` setting is enabled on your Apache server (it usually is), you can address your URL like this:

```
http://localhost/get.php/id=2/get=row
```

this will call `get.php`. The `id=2/get=row` part will be available in the `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` variable for you to split.

**mod_rewrite**

Alternatively, you could use mod_rewrite to map a URL according to a pre-defined pattern, like this:

```
http://localhost/2/row
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008491/apache-mod-rewrite-with-multiple-parameters) is a question dealing with how to use mod_rewrite; there are [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mod_rewrite%20parameters) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use URLRewriting
 if you are not a fan of having get variables in your URL but in response to you question the ? is part of the standard

if using apache user 
RewriteRule in .htaccess

Comment: He shouldn't use `&` outside their defined meaning, not even with mod_rewrite

Comment: @Pekka Agreed. Stick with standards